# Famous smoking mathematicians

Tags: math-history

I know Banach was an incessant smoker. I would like to know about the post 1950 famous smoking mathematicians?

This is a math-sociological question. Please do not view this as promoting anything.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this question is at all relevant to mathematics.

Comment: My former TA... Just joking. Yitang Zhang maybe? It is said that he came up with the main idea about proving there are infinite many pairs of prime numbers with difference less than $7 \times 10^7$ while smoking in his friend's home.

Comment: It's well-known that a mathematician is a machine for turning *coffee* into theorems.  I am not sure what, if anything, mathematicians turn cigarettes into.

Comment: Perhaps it might be even more interesting to know examples of mathematicians who provably smoked not only *tobacco*.

Comment: This question fits the math-history tag. I don't understand the closure operators. Please vote to reopen.

Comment: Smoking aside, the votes on closing and reopening this question itself is a great sociological experiment.

Comment: Von Neumann was a smoking mathematician who did not smoke. Similarly for Turing.

Comment: Andras Hajnal, Ronald Jensen, Bjarni Jonsson, Alfred Tarski.

Comment: A friend of mine who ran the coffee club at Madison years ago reported retrieving a coffee cup from Steve Wainger’s office and discovering that cleaning it was an exercise in archaeology: alternating layers of stogie ash and dried creamer residue.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if **G.H. Hardy** smoked a "lot". But this is the first picture that shows up when you google him.

[image]

And apparently **Bertrand Russell** is another on the list of Brits  posing with a pipe.

[image]

Comment: Well, considering there are only about 10 pictures of Hardy, some of which probably don't exist on the Internet, I'd say the probability of that is rather high... The other half of my point being that 10 pictures is a pretty small sample size...

Comment: Although, Hardy is definitely not post 1950. Interesting restriction that. post 1950

Comment: Presumably because pre-1950 basically everyone smoked who could afford it.

Comment: Yesh I guess it was a fashion. Especially if you chose to pose with a pipe in one of only a dozen portraits of yourself.

Comment: Since Hardy was extremely disturbed by his own image, the photograph was likely taken under duress anyway...

Comment: @Chappers The 1950 cutoff date is way too early for that. Smokophobia didn't really take off till a couple decades after that.

Comment: Hence I think the replies could be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I recall an anecdote recorded in James Gleick's book, *Chaos*: Friends of [Mitchell Feigenbaum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell_Feigenbaum) theorised he got his vitamins from cigarettes, since all he consumed otherwise was red meat, red wine, and coffee...

Answer (score 1):

Thomas Wolff was a Marlboro man: See [this](http://www.ams.org/notices/200105/fea-wolff.pdf).